# Parent Div's contents Zoom / Scale smoothly in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a zoomable div, when a user hovers over one of the divs then that specific div zooms, this currently works...

My issue is mainly with Safari when using CSS zoom, all of the contents within the div jump, at first it scales nicely and then the contents jump down to their original size, this issue does not occur in either Firefox and Chrome.

I do not know how i can replicate this issue so that you can see it working on your browser as there is currently no way i can host the site.

Here is my css of the main zoomable div :

MAIN DIV

```
    width:740px;
    height:150px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    transition:100ms;
    font-family: Rubik;
```

MAIN DIV HOVER

```
    border:1px solid #aaa;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 4px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 3px 4px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
transition:100ms;
cursor:pointer;
zoom:102%;
-ms-zoom: 1.02;
-webkit-zoom: 1.02;
-moz-transform:  scale(1.02,1.02);
transition: 250ms;
```

Im hoping someone has come across this issue in the past and will understand what i am referring to, is anyone has any suggestion to how i can replicate the issue so they can see it, i will do this. 
Thanks again

Comment: Please add a working example in fiddle and post the link here

Comment: I have just made a fiddle to show, the contents is a little messed up but if you run it in safari you will see the effect with the contents, thanks again

Comment: @San https://jsfiddle.net/04t5psbu/